# nvd3 - force all xaxis labels to show on line chart

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

how can I force all xAxis labels to show up on my graph without defining each tick via .tickvalues ?

I'm totally new to nvd3 and this is my first try.
Maybe there is someone with a good heart who can have a look at my code and help me out.
I did my research but nothing worked for me.

Here is my code:

```
var data = [
  {
"key": "www.WebsiteA.com",
"values": [ 

{date:"20151221",rank:1},
{date:"20151222",rank:3},
{date:"20151223",rank:2},
{date:"20151224",rank:4},
{date:"20151225",rank:2},
{date:"20151226",rank:5},
{date:"20151227",rank:3},
{date:"20151228",rank:2},
{date:"20151229",rank:2},
{date:"20151230",rank:1},
{date:"20151231",rank:2},
{date:"20160101",rank:4},
{date:"20160102",rank:5},
{date:"20160103",rank:3},

] },


   {
"key": "www.WebsiteB.com",
"values": [ 

{date:"20151221",rank:2},
{date:"20151222",rank:1},
{date:"20151223",rank:3},
{date:"20151224",rank:5},
{date:"20151225",rank:1},
{date:"20151226",rank:4},
{date:"20151227",rank:1},
{date:"20151228",rank:5},
{date:"20151229",rank:3},
{date:"20151230",rank:4},
{date:"20151231",rank:2},
{date:"20160101",rank:1},
{date:"20160102",rank:3},
{date:"20160103",rank:2},

] },   
 ]



nv.addGraph(function() {


  var chart = nv.models.lineChart()

  .x(function(d) {return d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse(d.date) })
  .y(function(d) {return d.rank})
  .yDomain([6, 1])  
  .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
  .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
  .margin({left: 100})
  .margin({right: 50})
  .margin({bottom: 100}) 
    ;




chart.legend.margin({top: 10, right:60, left:80, bottom: 100});

chart.xAxis
  .tickFormat(function(d) {return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(new Date(d)) })
  .rotateLabels(-45)
  ;

 chart.xScale(d3.time.scale()); //fixes misalignment of timescale with line graph

  chart.yAxis
    .axisLabel('Rank')
    .tickFormat(d3.format('d'))
  ;



  d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(data)
    .transition().duration(500)
    .call(chart)
    ;

 nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});
```

You can find the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Marei/1azqmx1L/3/

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think (I have only worked directly with d3 before, not nvd3) that you need to specify a list of xValues that you want to display using `tickValues()`.

So the first thing you need to do is to get a list of all your xValues (the order and/or duplicates do not matter):

```
//Map all xValues for each dataset to an array (tmp)
var tmp = data.map(function(e) {
    return e.values.map(function(d) {
        return d3.time.format('%Y%m%d').parse(d.date);
    });
});

//And flatten out that array, so you have all your xValues in a 1D-array
var xValues = [].concat.apply([], tmp);
```

Then use this to set that you want to display all xValues:

```
chart.xAxis
  .tickFormat(function(d) {return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(new Date(d)) })
  .rotateLabels(-45)
  .tickValues(xValues)
  .showMaxMin(false)
  ;
```

`showMaxMin` needs is set to `false` because otherwise all the end-values must be displayed

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly! Thanks a lot! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I have string values for x,
so, for tickValues() i created an index based array with items length like,

```
axisLabel: graph.x_label,
tickValues: Array.from({ length: graph.values.length }, (x, i) => i),
```